# Firebase @Exclude with kotlin data class

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have this data class in Kotlin (example):

```
import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude

data class User(val name: String = "", @Exclude val age: Int = 0)
```

And I don't want to save the age property in firebase. @Exclude should do this but it does not work, age is still saved.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: From what I read it should be the same but does prefixing `Exclude` with "field:" make any difference? `data class User(val name: String = "", @field:Exclude val age: Int = 0)`

Comment: Nope, doesn't make any difference, but @get:Exclude works (found it thanks to you). If you want post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah, and that makes sense now that you mention it too. Team effort!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Placing `@Exclude` on a property targets its generated field and not its generated get accesor method. To do the latter you'll need to prefix "Exclude" with "get:". e.g.:

```
data class User(val name: String = "", @get:Exclude val age: Int = 0)
```

See [Annotation Use-site Targets](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

Actually you don't need to add only `@get:Exclude` but you need **all 3 Exclude**,

@Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude.

I did it for `imageUrl` and `providerId`

```
data class FirebaseChatModel(
        @get:PropertyName("message")
        @set:PropertyName("message")
        var message: String = "",
        @get:PropertyName("type")
        @set:PropertyName("type")
        var type: Int = 1,
        @get:PropertyName("senderId")
        @set:PropertyName("senderId")
        var senderId: Int = 0,
        @get:PropertyName("receiverId")
        @set:PropertyName("receiverId")
        var receiverId: Int = 0,
        @Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude var imageUrl: String? = "",
        @Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude var providerId: Int = 0
)
```