# Firestore exclude data serialization

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've got several properties that should not be transferred to Firestore, such as metadata ("id" or "parent"), and with Firebase Realtime database, there was the option to set them to protected and make a getter to make them accessible to the outside world but not serialize to Firebase.

With Firestore the only option to prevent a property from serialization is to create a class with a private property and extend that. But this is not really useful as the property is not even accessible from inside the class.

Can you help me find a solution to create class properties that don't serialize to Firestore? (Maybe annotations?)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To mark a field as excluded from the Firestore or Realtime database you can use the [`@Exclude`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/android/Exclude) annotation. For example:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Model {
    @Exclude private String id;

    // ...
}
```

You can also use the [`@IgnoreExtraProperties`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/android/IgnoreExtraProperties) annotation against the class to automatically ignore properties that don't map to class fields.

Comment: Wow, knew there is a way with annotations, but it sadly wasn't documented anywhere!

Comment: Note that the @Exclude annotation comes from different packages for Firestore or RTDB.  '@com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude' respectively '@com.google.firebase.database.Exclude'

Comment: This didn't work for me. Apparently, if the variable is `private`, annotation doesn't work on it. In that case, add `@Exclude` on the `public` getter method.

Comment: For Firestore use com.google.cloud.firestore.annotation.Exclude import and it worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me. `@get:Exclude` with the property name plus `@IgnoreExtraProperties` at the class level worked. I have used this in kotlin.

Answer (score 40):

For **Kotlin** you need to make sure that the `getter` is annotated with the `@Exclude` annotation and not just the appropriate field. You can do this by specifying the target of the annotation. For example:

```
data class Model(@get:Exclude val id: String)
```

`@get` specifies that the `@Exclude` annotation should be added to the value's `getter`. See [Annotation Use-site Targets](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) docs for more information.

This also works for data classes.

Credits to [@mfulton26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3255152/mfulton26) for his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40117301/2739794.

Comment: I uses Kotlin data class and this solution works!

Comment: Perfect solution (like)

Answer (score 13):

[Grimthorr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115634/5250273) didn't work for me. So, I put `@Exclude` annotation before the getter method of the field I want to exclude from writing to Firestore db, and it worked:

```
@Exclude
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```