# How do I stop Firestore from saving all my data?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Cloud Firestore with Android Studio. I've noticed that it seems to save every field in a class to the database, not just to ones that have setters/getters. How do I stop this from happening?

For example, let's say I have a class called `Box`, defined like this:

```
private class Box {
     private int id;
     private String name, label;

     public Box(){}

     public void setId(int thisId) {id = thisId;}
     public void setName(String thisName) { name = thisName;}

     public int getId() { return id;}
     public String getName { return name;}

     public setup label () { ... }
}
```

I only have setters and getters for id and name, because they're the ones I want to save to the database. I don't want to save label, because it changes each time. However, it's saving it anyway, with a value of *null*.

What am I doing wrong? How do I stop it from saving a value for label?

Comment: Have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114024/firestore-exclude-data-serialization

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Didn't work for me. So, I put @Exclude annotation before the getter method of the field I want to exclude from writing to Firestore db, and it worked:

```
@Exclude
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

And remove @Exclude from the variable declaration, if it is an private modifier

Comment: Not working for me, I hope there is no any concern with language, as I used Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map to set the variables you want. Then send that map to firestore.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("id", "value");
map.put("name", "value");

firestore.collection("Your_collection_name).document(uid).add(map)...`
```

then you can add success listener or complete listener.

Comment: Thanks, but I’m trying to avoid using a map as it makes sub-data more awkward to save.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use default object serialization and also selectively remove properties that don't meet your criteria. Object serialization uses all available object properties all the time, regardless of their values. Unlike in Firebase Realtime database, where non-existing values are not displayed at all, in Cloud Firestore, if you create an object without setting its value, Firestore will assign the value of `null`.

If you don't want a value to be present in your database at all, you can use @Grimthorr's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114024/firestore-exclude-data-serialization) as @tyczj suggested in his comment.

To avoid having `null` properties in your database, as also @Raj suggested, you should use a `Map` containing only the properties of the document that you want to store. More important, you should also check each value for `null`, if you don't want to store `null` for a field. It is the only in which you can achieve this.

From the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document), this is how it should look like in code:

```
Map<String, Object> city = new HashMap<>();
city.put("name", "Los Angeles");
city.put("state", "CA");
city.put("country", "USA");
db.collection("cities").document("LA").set(city);
```

If your app is already launched and you have `null` values in your database, you can create a map and use `FieldValue.delete()` like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("yourField", FieldValue.delete());
yourRef.update(map);
```

The fields with `null` values won't be displayed anymore.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?