# W/Firestore: (24.1.2) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for about found on class

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know why I'm having this warning:

`W/Firestore: (24.1.2) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for about found on class`

Article Data Class:

```
data class Article(
    var img: String = "",
    var scientificName: String = ""
)
```

My Cloud Firestore:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the error messages says, you have a field named `about` in your document and there is no corresponding property in your `Article` class. You'll need to either add the missing property to your `Article` class, or mark the class with the [`IgnoreExtraProperties` annotation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/IgnoreExtraProperties) so that the mapper will ignore the field when reading the `Article` object from the document as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114024/firestore-exclude-data-serialization).

Comment: ohh okay i get it, thank you so much. I wanna ask, how to retrieve image from firestore ? thank in advance

Comment: That seems like a different question @AdeAdamNisaSabrina, so I recommend posting it in a separate question preferably with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you already tried and where you got stuck.