# Store protoc-gen-go generated struct to Firestore ignoring specific fields

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, protocol-buffers, protobuf-go

I have such a `Document` message that is being stored in Google Cloud Firestore:

```
message Document {
  string resource_name = 1 [(google.api.field_behavior) = OUTPUT_ONLY];
  string title = 2;
}
```

Setting such a Document to a `firestore.DocumentRef` directly results in both fields being stored as "ResourceName" and "Title" respectively.
I would like to store only "Title" and explicitly populate "resource_name" in my responses using the `ID` implicit in a `firestore.DocumentRef`.
I expected the `OUTPUT_ONLY` behaviour to be honoured in some way but it isn't.
Is there a known way to do this?

Here is a more detailed explanation:
When a document is stored to Firestore, a *uid* can be automatically assigned to the document:

```
document := Document{}
dRef := someCollection.NewDoc()
_, err = dRef.Set(ctx, &document)                    // stores 'ResourceName'!
```

Later I can retrieve that document by its *uid* as:

```
dRef := someCollection.Doc(uid)
dSnap, err := dRef.Get(ctx)
```

I would like to return that uid to the caller in the `resource_name` field (something like `"resourceName": "document/26b38366-1c57-4aa5-a6c1-bbff6a5119a5"`).
It could be as easy as:

```
document := Document{}      
dSnap.DataTo(&document)
document.ResourceName = "document/" + dSnap.Ref.ID
```

Since the document uid is implicit in the `firestore.DocumentRef` I don't want to store the field `ResourceName`, which I personally find redundant.
I have tried marshalling the Document first using `protojson`, but still, the field gets serialized too.
Alternatively, I tried marshalling the Document first using `protojson`, then unmarshalling the resulting `[]byte` to a `map[string]interface{}` that I can access to remove the `resourceName`.

I wonder if there is a way to do this in a less "hacky" way.

Comment: From what you explained, it’s similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114024/) past thread, is that right? For Go, you could use a plain `struct` and tag the `ResourceName` field with [`firestore:”-”`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef.Create) to make the Firebase SDK ignore it when storing documents. Is it one of your requirements using Protoc to generate the Struct?

Comment: Thanks. It's similar. I read about the `firestore:"-"` field, though our project requires that the data models/structs are generated by protoc.