# Flutter Firebase save JSON Object with nested List of custom Objects

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Custom Object `Wishlist` which I am `serializing` and saving/retrieving as `JSON` from `Firebase`.

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Wishlist {
  final String id;
  String name;
  List<Wish>? wishes;

  Wishlist({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    this.wishes,
  });

  factory Wishlist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$WishlistFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$WishlistToJson(this);
}
```

The thing is that I want `wishes` not to be saved as a `documentField` but as a `subCollection`.

How can I achieve that? Right now there is always a field `wishes` which is `null`. And then I save `wishes` in a `subcollection`. But that does not seem ideal.

How can I fix that? Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question, your actual schema looks like this:

```
db
|
--- wishlists (collection)
     |
     --- $wishlistId (document)
           |
           --- id: "wishlistId"
           |
           --- name: "wishlistName"
           |
           --- wishes: [wishObject, wishObject]
```

If you don't want `wishes` to be a field within a document, but a sub-collection, then you have to remove the `wishes` field from within your `Wishlist` class, and create a schema that looks like this:

```
db
|
--- wishlists (collection)
     |
     --- $wishlistId (document)
           |
           --- wishes (sub-collection) //
           |    |
           |    --- $docId (document)
           |         |
           |         --- //fields
           |
           --- id: "wishlistId"
           |
           --- name: "wishlistName"
```

**Edit:**

According to the latest comments, here is the solution for solving OP's problem.

If the `wishes` object is needed inside the `Wishlist` class, and you don't want to have that field present in the document in Firestore, then [you can use an annotation, and the field will be totally ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114024/firestore-exclude-data-serialization).