# Firestore kotlin data class @set:Exclude not working

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I don't want to write one field in my firestore.

I tried  `@Exclude` and it's not working,

tried `@set:Exclude var uId: String = ""`

and its also not working.

When I use `@get:Exclude`, I am able to exclude field while reading.

Comment: As you can see, I've already tried that solution which is not working, so it is not duplicate

Comment: You can find here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51165762/8874958